# Static dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dict = {}    
def Update_Dictionary(mydict,list,cmdId):    
    mydict['cmdid'] = list
    print mydict    
Update_Dictionary(dict,[1,2,3],1)
Update_Dictionary(dict,[4],2)
```

I need the dictionary to be updated not over written.
At the end I should have 2  key value pair.
Please help me in this.

Comment: Why not use built-in `dictionary.update() or setdefault()`

Comment: I think it should be `mydict[str(cmdid)] = list`

Comment: @IronFist: no need for `str()`, Python dictionary keys can be integers too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by a simple typographical error.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yea...I just thought that OP wanted them in `String` format....

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
mydict['cmdid'] = list
```

try

```
mydict[cmdId] = list
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes:

```
def Update_Dictionary(mydict,list,cmdId):    
    mydict[cmdId] = list
    print mydict
```

You are always assigning a new value for the literal string `'cmdid'` instead of the parameter `cmdId`.

Comment: At least take time to read the question, it's `cmdId` with a capital i letter.

Comment: Thx, changed it accordingly.